# Not able to connect to MySQL DB. Error mysql.connector not found

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am on Mac OS Mojave 
I am not able to read table data from local (in my machine) MySQL DB using Python3.7
Very new to python, so I downloaded Python3.7 then pip install mysql connector.
But when I import mysql.connector in the script I keep getting errors

I did the same pip install in the server running ubuntu and I was able to fetch data. Follow the same process in Mac and it does not work.

If I run import mysql.connector from IDLE and run the same file, it runs just fine.
But when I run the file through terminal it give me an error. 
I have so far added/updated env to include mysql connector. 
I am not sure what can I really do here
Looking for some help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare_vion_csc_with_cmdb.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .connection import MySQLConnection
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .network import MySQLUnixSocket, MySQLTCPSocket
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 33, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 52, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, selectors
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 12, in <module>
    import select
  File "/Users/skarki/Desktop/Python/Scripts/select.py", line 3, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'
```

Comment: Did you write `import mysql.connector` at the top of the file? Can you share the code you wrote in `select.py`?

Comment: Sure. Please see below for code:

import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="password",
  database="database"
)


mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)

Comment: The `select.py` in mysql connector is being shadowed by the `select.py` in the current directory.